# Problem in installing PHP 5.3.5 with apache 2.2.17 ( apache crashes)

Tags: php, apache, crash

I am trying to install PHP 5.3.5 ( using non Threaded x86 msi installer ) on windows 7 running  Apache 2.2.17.

After running the install program, Apache crashed. 
Anyone facing this problem? This is the latest build of PHP which was released on 6th Jan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason. There is a bug in this version of PHP installer (php-5.3.5-Win32-VC6-x86.msi). It adds incomplete values to httpd.conf file. Here is more detail about the bug : http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53696 and the fix.